# Horizontally scrolling treeview on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a treeview that is space limited, as such sometimes the treeview items can end up going outside the container.  To get around this I have made container overflow hidden and set up some javascript that auto scrolls horizontally as a user mouses over the various parts of the treeview.

This *almost* works but there is some slightly odd behaviour if you move slowly from one `li` to another.  If you move your mouse fast down the tree it behaves as expected but if you go slowly and back and forth sometimes the treeview bounces horizontally left to right.

To test this out try move from Folder 2 to Folder 3 and back again. What is happening here?

My JS code is below and you can [see all this happening in this fiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/6bkDF/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#addresspanel ul.treeview").on("mouseover", "li", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        console.log("mouseover", this, $(this).first().offset().left);
        $('#addresspanel ul:first').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $(this).first().offset().left
        }, 400);
        //$('#addresspanel ul:first').stop().animate({ "margin-left": -($(this).first().offset().left) }, 400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the `mouseover` to `mousemove`.

```
$(function () {
    $("#addresspanel ul.treeview").on("mousemove", "li", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        $('#addresspanel ul:first').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $(this).first().offset().left
        }, 400);

    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bkDF/1/